# Why do I keep losing the values of my struct members?

Tags: c, if-statement, struct

apologies if this is some stupid mistake I've made, I'm just a rookie.

First off, I have created a struct;

```
struct StarsStruct
{
    int SerialNumber;
    char StarName[10];
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

Then, I've created an array of struct pointers using; (NumberOfStars is just an int variable) This was declared and initialised at the top of the program, before any if statements.

```
struct StarsStruct *Stars = malloc(sizeof(struct StarsStruct) * NumberOfStars);
```

And I have done a for loop to change the values of the members, in my struct array;

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfStars; i++)
        {
            r1 = rand() % (60 + 1 - 0) + 0;
            r2 = rand() % (30 + 1 - 0) + 0;


            Stars[i].SerialNumber = i;
            Stars[i].x = r1;
            Stars[i].y = r2;
            Plot(r1, r2, '.');
        }
```

However, when I go to my second IF statement, for some reason these values are completely  erased;

full part of the code;

```
if (strcmp(CurrentCommand, "bang") == 0)
    {
        Clear();
        printf("Enter the number of stars to be created: ");
        scanf("%d", &NumberOfStars);

        //Stars = malloc(sizeof(struct StarsStruct) * NumberOfStars);

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfStars; i++)
        {
            r1 = rand() % (60 + 1 - 0) + 0;
            r2 = rand() % (30 + 1 - 0) + 0;


            Stars[i].SerialNumber = i;
            Stars[i].x = r1;
            Stars[i].y = r2;
            Plot(r1, r2, '.');
        }

    }


    else if (strcmp(CurrentCommand, "list") == 0)
    {
        Stars[0].SerialNumber;
        Stars[1].y;
        Stars[2].SerialNumber;
        Stars[3].SerialNumber;
        Stars[4].x;
        Stars[5].y;
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfStars; i++)
        {

            printf("%d", Stars[0].SerialNumber);

        }
    }
```

[image: FIRST IF STATEMENT]

[image: SECOND IF STATEMENT]

Comment: It's not a second if statement, it's an else if statement.  You can't go in to both sections.

Comment: You need to show more context in your function.  It's not clear how each part is called and what you're doing with `Stars`.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your IDE unless your question is about the IDE itself. Create and post a [mcve] (as text).

Comment: So, when you go into your "second if statament", are you sure that you already executed your "first if statement" before that? How does the whole thing work? Your "full part of the code" does not makes it clearer at all.

Comment: These statements do nothing: `Stars[0].SerialNumber;`
        `Stars[1].y;`
        `Stars[2].SerialNumber;`
        `Stars[3].SerialNumber;`
        `Stars[4].x;`
        `Stars[5].y;`

Comment: @Erik W: The OP knows, apparently. They put it there just to be able to check the values by aiming at them with the mouse. It makes no sense, but still...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* `malloc()` returns uninitlized memory. Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.4

> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and
>   whose value is indeterminate.

In the `else if` part, (when you reach there), you don't have the members initialized, because, you did not enter the `if` block which takes care of assigning the values!!

Once again, `C11`, chapter §6.8.4.1,

> In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0. In the `else` form, the second substatement is executed if the expression compares equal to 0. [...]

You need to move the assignment part outside of the `if` condition, if you want the values to be "available" in the `else` block also.